# Are 15 reputation points sufficient for accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation

If a question has not been answered, it lacks exposure, it becomes forgotten, and consequently, fails to attract upvotes.

By answering these types of questions, a user is providing a service, but due to the question's low views count and number of upvotes, an answer — however good — will naturally be penalized.

I have answered many questions that were left on the heap, and my answers were accepted but none of them had more than 3 upvotes.

In similar cases, wouldn't it be better to increase the number of rep, presently at 15 points, for an accepted answer? By doing so, new users like myself would be encouraged to answer these unanswered questions.

Comment: Writte a better answer, get more upvotes

Comment: The problem is a few people read that answers.

Comment: If you write a good answer, the upvotes will come.

Comment: But how? In google search only famous posts are shown. The questions that are not public and especially is for one person, how could be high visited?

Comment: Questions get visits, good questions get more visits. Answer good questions with good answer, you'll get your upvotes. Btw: 2-3 upvotes and an accept is totally acceptable for a decent answer.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi So then don't focus on answering questions that are only ever useful to one person.  We don't want questions like that here in the first place.  Focus on answering questions that will actually be useful to people other than the question author.  We don't *want* to encourage more questions that only ever help the question author.

Comment: @Servy, The point is these questions are asked previousely, and not remained for me!

Comment: @FarzinKanzi Every single question that might be useful to multiple people has not in fact been asked and answered.  I can assure you of that.  And if it were, that still doesn't mean we should work harder to reward people from creating content that's not helpful.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi "The questions that are not public" ??? All questions are public.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reputation was meant to reflect how many people found your contribution useful — while accepting an answer is the choice of ONE user.

The author can up-vote your post (10 rep), and accepting your answer adds an ***additional*** 15 rep over *that.* Accepting an answer also pins the post to the top of the list, which overrides what everyone actually voted on as the best answer. That gives the post even *more* exposure still.

I believe the benefits of accepting an answer are over-weighted enough to leave it as is.